# parsing parent/children relationship of XML elements

Tags: python, xml, bash, perl, xml-parsing

Given the following XML (ant build xml):

```
    <project name="pj1">
        <target name="t1">
            ...
            <antcall target="t2"/>
            <a>
                <antcall target="t4"/>
            </a>
            ...
        </target>
        <target name="t2">
            ...
            <antcall target="t3"/>
            ...
        </target>
        <target name="t3">
            ...
            ...
        </target>
        <target name="t4">
            ...
            <antcall target="t2"/>
            ...
        </target>
        <target name="t5">
            ...
            ...
        </target>
    </project>
```

I'd like to display parent/children relationship of the target elements as follows (without displaying a target as first level element if it is nested in another target)

```
t1
    t2
        t3
    t4
        t2
            t3
t5
```

could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened to the `t2`/`t3` target pair?

Comment: just corrected my question. thank you for spotting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to manipulate an XML tree to some other representation, I find it useful to first convert it to an abstract representation and then convert to the final concrete representation.

In this case, first we create a dictionary of lists which represent the target dependency structure, then we pretty-print that dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import chain

def parse(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    result = {}
    for target in root.findall('target'):
        target_name = target.get('name')
        result[target_name] = []
        for antcall in target.findall('.//antcall'):
            result[target_name].append(antcall.get('target'))
    return result

def display(tree):
    def recurse(node, indent):
        print "%*s%s"%(indent*4, "", node)
        for node in sorted(tree[node]):
            recurse(node, indent+1)
    for item in sorted(tree):
        if item in chain(*tree.values()): continue
        recurse(item,0)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dump ANT files')
    parser.add_argument('antfile',
                        nargs='+',
                        type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                        help='ANT build file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    for antfile in args.antfile:
        display(parse(antfile))
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. the code works but in my case the "antcall" element might not be the immediate next element under the "target" element, it could be one or more levels under. that is to say, they can appear deeper into the document tree...and each "target" contain more than one "antcall" elements.

Comment: re: "not imediate next element under", you can use an XPath expression in `target.findall()`. re: "more than one 'antcall'", you can store them in a list in the dictionary. See my recent edit.

Comment: Thank you so much Rob. a perfect one.